# Gauge fixing in derivation of fractional QHE action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

I'll copy the text from a relevant [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362585/):

> This follows the discussion in *Altland and Simons Condensed Matter
> Field Theory -- section 9.5* on deriving the Chern-Simons action for
> FQHE.
>
> Starting with the real-time field integral representation:
> $\mathcal{Z} = \mathcal{N} \int
> D(\bar{\psi},\psi)e^{iS[\bar{\psi},\psi]}$ where
>
> \begin{equation} S[\bar{\psi},\psi] = \int dt \, d^2x \, \bar{\psi}
> \bigg(i\partial_t + \mu - \frac{1}{2m} (-i\partial_x +
> \mathbf{A}[\bar{\psi},\psi])^2 - V(\mathbf{x}) \bigg)\psi
> \end{equation}
>
> $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}_\text{ext} + \mathbf{a}$, with
> $\mathbf{A}_\text{ext}$ is the vector potential of the magnetic field
> responsible for the QHE and $\mathbf{a}$ is the vector potential from
> the phases factor of the singular gauge transformation
>
> \begin{equation} \Psi(\mathbf{x}_1,...) \rightarrow
>  \Psi(\mathbf{x}_1,...) \exp \big(-2is \sum_{i<j}
>  \text{arg}(\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j)  \big) \end{equation}
>
> As stated in the book, $\mathbf{A}$ present a complication that can be
> avoided by **promoting the vector potential to an integration variable
> whose value is set so as to generate the flux pattern**. This is done
> by multiplying $\mathcal{Z}$ by
>
> \begin{equation} (1) \qquad \qquad 1=\mathcal{N}\int D\mathbf{a_\perp}
> \prod_{\mathbf{x},t} \, \delta\big(b(\mathbf{x},t)+4\pi s
>  \rho(\mathbf{x},t)\big) \end{equation}
>
> where $b=\epsilon_{ij} \partial_i (a_\perp)_j$ and the subscript
> "$\perp$" indicates that the integration extends only over transversal
> configuration of the vector potential (i.e. $\partial_i a_i =0$). This
> results to
>
> \begin{equation} (2) \qquad \mathcal{Z} = \mathcal{N} \int
>  D(\bar{\psi},\psi) D\mathbf{a_\perp} \prod_{\mathbf{x},t} \,
>  \delta\big(b(\mathbf{x},t)+4\pi s \rho(\mathbf{x},t)\big)
>  \exp\big[-S[\bar{\psi},\psi,\mathbf{a}_\perp] \big] \end{equation}
> \begin{equation} (3) \qquad \mathcal{Z} = \mathcal{N} \int
>  D(\bar{\psi},\psi) D\mathbf{a_\perp} D\phi \exp \bigg(
>  iS[\bar{\psi},\psi,\mathbf{a}_\perp] - i\int dt\, d^2x \, \phi (b/4\pi
>  s + \rho ) \bigg) \end{equation}

I don't understand why we integrate over gauge potentials in the Coulomb gauge only? Altland and Simons claims this is because the gauge potential

\begin{align}
\mathbf{a}=-2s\int {\rm d}^2{x'} \frac{\hat{z} \times (x-x')}{|x-x'|^2}\rho(x')
\end{align}

is transverse i.e. $\nabla \cdot \textbf{a} = 0$. However the condition $b+4\pi s\rho=0$
that is used to promote the vector potential to an integration variable is gauge-invariant, so it should not matter what gauge I am working in, right?

Isn't there a direct way to get to the gauge-invariant expression $\mathcal{L}_{CS}=\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho} a_\mu \partial_\nu a_\rho$? for the Chern-Simons term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

1. When performing the gauge transformation $ U = \exp \big(-2is \sum_{i<j} \text{arg}(\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j)  \big) $ you can show that
   $$ U^{-1}\Big(-i\mathbf{\nabla} + \mathbf{A_{\text{ext}}} \Big)U = \Big(-i\mathbf{\nabla} + \mathbf{A_{\text{ext}}} + \mathbf{a} \Big), $$
   with $ \mathbf{a}=-2s\int {\rm d}^2{x'} \frac{\hat{z} \times (x-x')}{|x-x'|^2}\rho(x') $. Hence your statistical field $ \mathbf{a} $ is fixed in this case. The gauge redundancy would come from amending the gauge transformation with an irrelevant phase factor: $ \tilde U = U e^{i\phi(\mathbf{x})} $.
   So when now implementing the $ \mathbf{a} $ field in the path integral, we need to remember that it is only uniquely defined when considering the two equations:
   $$ \mathbf{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{a} + 4\pi s \rho = 0, $$
   and
   $$ \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{a} = 0. $$
   Thus, you multiply the path integral with a delta function enforcing the first equation and say you only integrate over transverse fields $ \mathbf{a_{\perp}} $.
2. Actually, we have already obtained the reasonable path integral where we get rid of the gauge redundancy above. If we ask ourselves, what is the gauge-invariant term in the Lagrangian that still gives us the first defining equation from above, the answer is indeed the Chern-Simons term. Bare in mind though that the full Chern-Simons term $ ada $ will have an additional factor of $ \frac{1}{2} $ compared to the $ a_0 \mathbf{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{a} $ term because there are two such terms in the full Chern-Simons term.